# Mongoose populate() is returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose populate function but in response I am getting empty array. I know there are several questions talking about the same subject but none worked for my case.

**My objective** is to populate my Order document.

This is how my schemas are organized:

*Menu.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const Food = require("./Food");
const Drink = require("./Drink");

const MenuSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  food: {
    type: [Food.schema],
    required: false,
  },
  drinks: {
    type: [Drink.schema],
    required: false,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Menu", MenuSchema);
```

**Note**: Im using Food.schema and Drink.schema inside my Arrays instead of making a ref. Im storing the Food and Drink models inside of the Menu model

*Food.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const FoodSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ingredients: {
    type: [],
    required: false,
    default: [],
  },
  stock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["starter", "main", "dessert"],
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Food", FoodSchema);
```

*Drink.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const DrinkSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  stock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Drink", DrinkSchema);
```

*Order.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["restaurant", "takeaway", "delivery"],
  },
  food: {
    type: [{ type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: "Food" }],
    required: false,
    default: [],
  },
  drinks: {
    type: [{ type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: "Drink" }],
    required: false,
    default: [],
  },
  orderValue: Number,
  client_id: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    ref: "Client",
    required: false,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

This is the **controller** where I'm trying to make my populate work. Whenever I remove the populate method I get the _id references for the Food and Drink arrays.

*TableController.js*

```
exports.getOrderFromTable = async (req, res) => {
  const { code, tableCode } = req.params;
  try {
    const foundRestaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({ code: code });
    const foundTable = foundRestaurant.tables.filter(
      (table) => table.code == tableCode
    );
    console.log(foundTable[0].order_id);
    const foundOrder = await Order.findOne({
      _id: foundTable[0].order_id,
    })
      .populate("food")
      .populate("drinks");
    res.send(foundOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

And this is what the **mongoose debugger** returns when I run the controller:

```
Mongoose: restaurants.findOne({ code: new ObjectId("62a60dcb9fe25d276815675c") }, { projection: {} })
new ObjectId("62a60ece9fe25d27681567b7")
Mongoose: orders.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("62a60ece9fe25d27681567b7") }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: foods.find({ _id: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("62a60e039fe25d276815677d"), new ObjectId("62a60e169fe25d2768156785") ], [Symbol(mongoose#trustedSymbol)]: true }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: {}})
Mongoose: drinks.find({ _id: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("62a60e259fe25d276815678d"), new ObjectId("62a60e3c9fe25d276815679c") ], [Symbol(mongoose#trustedSymbol)]: true }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: {}})
```

And finally this is the JSON file I get when I do a GET http request using Postman:

```
{
    "_id": "62a60ece9fe25d27681567b7",
    "code": "62a60ece9fe25d27681567b6",
    "type": "restaurant",
    "food": [],
    "drinks": [],
    "orderValue": 25,
    "createdAt": "2022-06-12T16:05:34.513Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Thank you for any help. I've been really struggling with this method.